# 'Undefined Reference' compiling Cairo program - despite trying solutions to similar questions

Tags: c, compilation, cairo

**Note: This question is NOT a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35743948/cairo-compiling-error-undefined-reference) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19992604/using-gcc-i-am-unable-to-get-3rd-party-library-cairo-to-link-compile) - those solutions *do not* work for me.**

I am trying to compile a program using Cairo. I have copied my code directly from [the Cairo FAQ](https://www.cairographics.org/FAQ/#compilation_flags):

```
#include <cairo.h>

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
        cairo_surface_t *surface =
            cairo_image_surface_create (CAIRO_FORMAT_ARGB32, 240, 80);
        cairo_t *cr =
            cairo_create (surface);

        cairo_select_font_face (cr, "serif", CAIRO_FONT_SLANT_NORMAL, CAIRO_FONT_WEIGHT_BOLD);
        cairo_set_font_size (cr, 32.0);
        cairo_set_source_rgb (cr, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
        cairo_move_to (cr, 10.0, 50.0);
        cairo_show_text (cr, "Hello, world");

        cairo_destroy (cr);
        cairo_surface_write_to_png (surface, "hello.png");
        cairo_surface_destroy (surface);
        return 0;
}
```

I have installed `libcairo2-dev` (XUbuntu 16.04.) Cairo is located in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`. I have written a makefile that makes use of `pkg-config` to identify the proper libraries:

```
CC=cc
CFLAGS=$(shell pkg-config --cflags cairo)
LFLAGS=-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu $(shell pkg-config --libs cairo)

OBJECTS=main.o
BIN=main

$(BIN): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(LFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $(BIN)

%.o: %.c
    gcc -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -rf *.o
```

Yet, when I run `make`:

```
cc -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lcairo main.o -o main
main.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x1f): undefined reference to `cairo_image_surface_create'
main.c:(.text+0x2f): undefined reference to `cairo_create'
main.c:(.text+0x4e): undefined reference to `cairo_select_font_face'
main.c:(.text+0x6d): undefined reference to `cairo_set_font_size'
main.c:(.text+0x89): undefined reference to `cairo_set_source_rgb'
main.c:(.text+0xb4): undefined reference to `cairo_move_to'
main.c:(.text+0xc5): undefined reference to `cairo_show_text'
main.c:(.text+0xd1): undefined reference to `cairo_destroy'
main.c:(.text+0xe2): undefined reference to `cairo_surface_write_to_png'
main.c:(.text+0xee): undefined reference to `cairo_surface_destroy'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:9: recipe for target 'main' failed
make: *** [main] Error 1
```

Comment: Order of object files and libraries when linking is important. Place the `-lcairo` option *last*, after the `main.o` object file.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yep, there we go. I always screw up the order :/